# Handling the receiving data from the sensor as it creates a queue I guess because it shows data on the terminal even when sensor is disconnected?

Tags: embedded, iot, uart, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using PMS sensor with the environment of micropython with thonny and using the RP pico W as my controller and I am just trying to receive the data from the sensor and so when I disconnect the sensor, it still logs the data for like 7-8 iterations and this happens depending upon the sleep time as well.

For example, when every iteration runs after a delay of 1 s, it disconnects and the terminal shows no data as soon as I switch the power off from the sensor but when I change it to a delay of 5 or greater than 10 sec, the iterations start to increase as soon as the sensor is disconnected. I am a beginner working with RP PICO W So any help would be appreciated.

Tried with a delay of 1s it works fine but as I increase the delay, the terminal starts showing data for 7-8 iterations depending upon the delay using time.sleep() function although the sensor is disconnected.

Here is how I am reading data after validation checks for frame header and checksum match:

```py
    while True:
            if uart.any():
                data = uart.read(32)
                if data:
                    pmData, isValid = parseData(data)
                    if isValid:
                        print(f"PM 1.0: {pmData['pm1_0']}, PM 2.5: {pmData['pm2_5']}, PM 10: {pmData['pm10']}")
```

Comment: parseData is a function which is responsible for checking the frame header and validating both checksums(one being the checksum of the receivedData and the other one is a calculated one that we know what the checksum should be) So basically when data is available it checks the frame header first and then the checksum and if these conditions remain valid, it then stores the parsed data of respective bytes of packet of data to pmData variable

Comment: You only mention a programming language (for your user app) and the hardware (i.e. "*RP pico W*"). What's is in between? Is there a Linux kernel? If so, then your app is not "reading" from the UART hardware, but merely fetching bytes from a system buffer. See 
[Linux serial drivers](https://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html), esp Fig.3. Your program is not synchronized with the the arrival of data at the HW level. Nor does the "read" rate by your program seem to match the rate the sensor sends its measurements. How often does the sensor send a sampling?

Comment: Your program that sleeps for a "long" delay allows the system buffer to fill up with one or more complete messages before your program ever tries to fetch data. If you use blocking reads, then there's no need to explicitly sleep, and your program will be able to read the data as fast as it arrives/processed. The typical problem with a blocking (raw) read (instead of sleeping/waiting and then "reading") is that you may get a message fragment, and have to issue more reads to obtain a complete message.

Comment: @sawdust I would assume that the sensor has a serial interface and that this _is_ embedded code.  Nonetheless, the UART is still buffered and asynchronous, so your point still applies.

Comment: @ShahzebKhan Details if the sensor required.  Don't assume that anyone knows what "PMS", or whether that information is relevant.  From the code, it appears that the sensor has a UART serial interface, but you have not stated that, which is relevant.  The UART driver is buffered, and you are reading it periodically rather than in real time. Also it is implicit from the code that the sensor outputs data asynchronously (it is not polled).  You should process data as it arrived rather than periodically, otherwise the data may be out of date or no longer valid at the time you read it.

Comment: Moreover reading in chunks of 32 bytes then parsing is not robust for asynchronous data.  It is possible to get out of sync and end up with the end of one packet, ant the start of the next, rather than a single complete packet.  Normally you would inspect one byte atv a time to find the start of a packet, continue reading to the end of the packet, then parse the collated packet.

Comment: There is no delay in the code presented.

Comment: "_Here is how I am reading data after validation checks for frame header and checksum match:_" : How can you have performed those checks if you have not yet read the data from the UART?  Very little about your question makes much sense. You have omitted a great deal if information.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.UART.html#machine-uart

`UART.init` has an argument to set the length of the Rx buffer, it is not stated what the default is.  The UART will be serviced asynchronously (in interrupt) and received data will be placed in a FIFO buffer.  The buffer is what you read with `UART.read`, it does not read the UART directly.

`UART.any` tests whether the buffer is not empty.

`UART.read( 32 )` will read *upto* 32 characters from the buffer.  If there are fewer than 32 characters, it will return after a timeout (also defined by `UART.init`).

If the sensor outputs asynchronously, then during any delay, data will be buffered.  A delay is probably ill-advised for asynchronous (rather than polled) sensor data.  You should retrieve data as it becomes available in *real-time*.